# Rails 4: assets are precompiled, but stylesheet_link_tag generates non-precompiled paths

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline, capistrano3

I'm using Rails 4.2.3 and Capistrano 3 to deploy my application, and have a problem with the assets. During deploy I can see that precompile step succeeds (and there are actual bundled digested files in `/public/assets` folder, as well as the manifest file), but `stylesheet_link_tag` helper still generates links as if assets weren't precompiled:

```
<link href="/stylesheets/scaffold.css?1458015955" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/stylesheets/dropdown.css?1458015955" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

This is what `application.css` file looks like:

```
/* 
 *= require scaffold
 *= require dropdown

 *= require_self
 */
```

I found in Rails docs that `stylesheet_link_tag` behaves this way when asset pipeline is disabled, but I don't think this is the case. This is what I have inside `environments/staging.rb` file:

```
config.assets.enabled = true
config.serve_static_files = false
config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
config.assets.compile = false
config.assets.digest = true
config.assets.debug = false
```

How would you recommend to debug this problem? Any advise would be very appreciated

Comment: Could you double-check what environment your app is running under? Make sure that RAILS_ENV=staging.